# What is/are the plural/s of "people person"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Product Owners are supposed to be people people... people persons... persons persons? people's people? people person's? people with people skills.

What is/are the plural/s of "people person"?

Answer (score 1):

The plural of *people person* has to be *people people*. However, as your question implies, this is at least a little bit problematic.

In speech, you can use emphasis/tone to get this across: "Product owners are *people* people." In other media, I suppose you might need some extra words to verify for your audience that you didn't just type the word out twice by mistake.

There may be other terms to answer your question, but those will be non-optimal because the simple plural in this case is, as far as I can tell, the correct one.

Comment: Would a person who specialises in knowing people people be a people people person, and would the plural be people people people?

Comment: @fredley you're such a people people people person. The world needs more people like you: more people people people people.

Comment: @badp I'm going to the people people people people to get some people people people.

Comment: @fredley do you think the people of people people people people will be on board? The people people people people people is a touchy one.

Comment: People people people people people people people [people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gG62zay3kck